# Openshift : AlertManager going on CrashLoopBackOff , Prometheus Operator

Tags: openshift, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

Configured AlertManager for Prometheus with Promethus Operator facing below error ad Alertmanager is going on  CrashLoopBackOff

```
level=info ts=2020-02-19T15:42:37.782116642Z caller=main.go:140 msg="Starting Alertmanager" version="(version=0.17.0, branch=HEAD, revision=c7551cd75c414dc81df027f691e2eb21d4fd85b2)"
level=info ts=2020-02-19T15:42:37.782197318Z caller=main.go:141 build_context="(go=go1.12.4, user=root@932a86a52b76, date=20190503-09:10:07)"
level=warn ts=2020-02-19T15:42:37.798588642Z caller=cluster.go:226 component=cluster msg="failed to join cluster" err="1 error occurred:\n\t* Failed to resolve alertmanager-alert-manager-0.alertmanager-operated.apparc-t.svc:9094: lookup alertmanager-alert-manager-0.alertmanager-operated.apparc-t.svc on 172.22.32.247:53: no such host\n\n"
level=info ts=2020-02-19T15:42:37.798644614Z caller=cluster.go:228 component=cluster msg="will retry joining cluster every 10s"
level=warn ts=2020-02-19T15:42:37.798665045Z caller=main.go:230 msg="unable to join gossip mesh" err="1 error occurred:\n\t* Failed to resolve alertmanager-alert-manager-0.alertmanager-operated.apparc-t.svc:9094: lookup alertmanager-alert-manager-0.alertmanager-operated.apparc-t.svc on 172.22.32.247:53: no such host\n\n"
level=info ts=2020-02-19T15:42:37.800267708Z caller=cluster.go:613 component=cluster msg="Waiting for gossip to settle..." interval=2s
level=info ts=2020-02-19T15:42:37.825176577Z caller=coordinator.go:119 component=configuration msg="Loading configuration file" file=/etc/alertmanager/config/alertmanager.yaml
```